# MSAccess - Select & Insert Into - in chunks?

Tags: ms-access

I have a routine that grabs data from a linked SQL Server into a local table:

```
Set db = CurrentDb()
db.QueryTimeout = 0
...
strSql = "INSERT INTO Item " & _
        "SELECT dbo_Item.* " & _
        "FROM dbo_Item " & _
        "WHERE dbo_Item.MASTER_INVID = " & TempVars!my_InvID
    db.Execute strSql
```

Problem is some of these datasets can be very large (>500K records, ~750MB in size).

I get odd issues with some user due to the potentially LONG fetch process, and possibly some intermittency in their internet connections.

Question:  Is it possible/feasible to break this task into chunks?  Grabbing blocks of records from the dbo recordset and inserting/appending to my local table.  Can I select ~50K blocks of records via a query?

I do know the row_count (via DCount query) in advance, so I could compute the number of chunks, and also show some progress (Chunk 1 of 10...) type message to my users.

Note:  Oddity - Usually my users will see an error message, but many times the current fetch method will just give up without complaint and return control to the initiating Form.  I have seen myself in my own session.

Comment: 500K+? It's time to migrate to SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server at local user workstations is not feasible at this time.  The data needs to reside in local MS Access tables/app among many users.  Once data review/manipulation is complete, results are sent back to the server.  Review and edit performance via ODBC is terrible.

Comment: What is the datatype of the InvID and what SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: I think I have a workable solution.  There is another attribute, InputID, machine generated, auto incremented.  I can determine the Max and Min values of the InputID, then Select record sets in bunches over a range of InputIDs (i.e., Chunk = RecordCount/100), Then increment the range for the next chunk and repeat.  The InputID is not perfectly sequential, there are gaps introduced by upstream processes, but should be workable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my approach - leveraging an auto incremented attribute "clientinputid" 1/:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim intRecordQty As Long
Dim intMin As Long
Dim intMax As Long
Dim intChunk As Long
Dim intCount As Long
Dim intQty As Long
Dim strSql As String

Set db = CurrentDb()

'unrelated code snipped....

intRecordQty = DCount("[dbo_Item.InvID]", "dbo_Item", "[InvID] = " & TempVars!my_InvID)

intMin = DMin("clientinputid", "dbo_Item", "[InvID] = " & TempVars!my_InvID)
intMax = DMax("clientinputid", "dbo_Item", "[InvID] = " & TempVars!my_InvID)

Select Case intRecordQty
    Case 0 To 10000
        intChunk = (intMax - intMin) / 2
    Case 10001 To 25000
        intChunk = (intMax - intMin) / 4
    Case 25001 To 100000
        intChunk = (intMax - intMin) / 10
    Case Is > 100001
        intChunk = (intMax - intMin) / 100
    End Select

intQty = intRecordQty / intChunk
intCount = intMin

Do While intCount < intMax
    strSql = "INSERT INTO Item " & _
        "SELECT dbo_Item.* " & _
        "FROM dbo_Item " & _
        "WHERE dbo_Item.clientinputid between " & intCount & " and " & (intCount + intChunk) & " and dbo_Item.MASTER_INVID = " & TempVars!my_InvID
    db.Execute strSql
    DoEvents

    intCount = intCount + intChunk + 1

Loop

'more unrelated code snipped....
```

1/ - clientinputid is machine-generated as an auto-increment field.  There are holes in the range of values, introduced by upstream processes. Seems to be workable, though I do not know if always true for every InvID.